# http request for another external url

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

So right now I've implemented my Webhook that can answer basic questions from user by using action trigger functions. However, what if I want to make an external http request from an url, for example, "http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json". I use the request module and it seems not working/responding after the line I made the request, or use anything from request such as req.body (Actually it just gives me NOT AVAILABLE in api.ai when I typed in the triggering intent). The functions can be deployed with no problem, but I am justing wondering how to make it work. Thanks a ton in advance.

```
function fetch_query(assistant){
    const intent = assistant.getIntent();
    let item = '';
    if (intent == 'input.loc')
        item = 'iss_position';
    else if (intent == 'input.msg')
        item = 'message';
    else if (intent == 'input.time')
        item = 'timestamp'
    var req = request('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json',
        function (error, response, body){
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                console.log('request successful!');
            }
        });
    var input = JSON.parse(req.body);
    for (var i in input){
        if (i == item){
            const speech = `<speak> ${input[i]} </speak>`;
            assistant.ask(speech);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're handling the action trigger and where you're trying to make the request?

Comment: @Prisoner posted. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Prisoner for answering this question. To make external request through firebase cloud functions, one needs to get the paid plans. If the data is not that big and no need for using the database, I recommend go blaze: 
https://firebase.google.com/pricing/
After purchase, just go deploy your functions again and it should work for the api.ai/action simulator to dynamically query something.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that your call to `request()` isn't doing the work in the callback function. I'm not entirely sure what `request()` returns in this case, but it sounds like it is something that is meant to be fed into a pipe, and not something that blocks until it returns and contains a `body` property.

The solution for this part would be to move your processing inside the callback. So something more like this:

```
request('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json',
    function (error, response, body){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            console.log('request successful!');

            var input = JSON.parse(body);
            // Do something with the body here
            // including calling assistant.ask()
        }
    });
```

(As a point of style, you probably don't need the for-in loop there, since you're just testing to be sure that the property name equals item. Just get the value of `input[item]` and use that value. The loop is confusing, since it suggests that you might be calling `assistant.ask()` more than once - which you can't do.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing it out for the loop issue. After change it still does not work. Actually, I tried this before I changed it to the return request case. To me, it never gets into the request, have you tested on your side? Does it work?

Comment: In fact, I think the AOG does not support the request within the function call. From the limited documentation posted by google, I haven't seen any related to this, but it's one of the most important functionality that it needs to support for dynamically query something from the external website/url rather than just hardcode/type response in the api.ai console.

Comment: Well it turns out it's due to the firebase. My previous and your version both work, but it does not support external url for free service, we've to enabled the blame plan.

Comment: I've added a few tags to supplement this. You may want to write up your answer as a new answer and accept it.